# What takes so much memory on my almost static web page?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, web, memory-leaks

I loaded my web page in Chrome, and opened Chrome's task manager(SHIFT_ESC). The process that loads my page quickly consumes over 100M of memory, while most other tabs only takes 20-30M.

My page is a very simple product landing page, mostly static. Initially I put in some gif animation, I know Chrome has a memory leak bug when handling certain gif files, so I remove the gif and use png files, and write some javascript animation(mostly jquery.hide .animate calls). It solves the memory leak problem(with gif memory leak, Chrome consumes close to 1G of memory in a minute), but the page still takes much more memory than other web pages.

Then I thought maybe there are memory leaks in my js code, which is very unlikely, because it has very little js. Anyway, I commented all js code, and reload the page(kill every Chrome process and restart), it still takes over 100M of memory...

Now I am at my wit's end. What static resources (css, html) could take so much memory? What is happening within the browser?

Comment: Google Chrome has a strange behavior when talking about memory management. It treats every tab as a separate process so every tab is independent from the others and will not affect the rest of them in case of malfunction. By the way, you should at least show the code of the page (or maybe some link to it) in order to take a look at it somehow.

Comment: @NeoWang Take a look at [JavaScript Memory Profiling](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling) of Chrome DevTools, it saved me a couple of times!